# SymPy cannot evaluate dot product of *metamorphosed* vectors

Tags: python, sympy

I am working with SymPy `vector`s:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import *
N = CoordSys3D('N')
x = symbols('x')
v = x * N.i + x**2 * N.j
vf=factor(v)
vf1=vf.as_independent(Vector)[1]
type(vf1)
# sympy.core.add.Add
```

I need to calculate `dot(vf1,vf1)`. But SymPy does not evaluate the dot product:

```
ss = dot(vf1,vf1)
ss
# 1 + 2*Dot(N.i, N.j*x) + Dot(N.j*x, N.j*x)
```

I suspect, this is because `vf1` has been *metamorphosed* into another type, i.e. `sympy.core.add.Add`).

Is there a way to make SymPy evaluate `ss`? Is there a way to cast `vf1` as a `sympy.vector...`?

**EDIT**

I have written a function that does the dot product. But I need to do this the SymPy way, so I don't have to re-implement my own version of every function in `sympy.vector`.

Comment: what result do you expect? As for me in `ss` you get evaluated result - `a**2 + 2*a*b + b**2`. Maybe for more you have to use values in place of `x`, `N`.

Comment: As I mentioned, I get `1 + 2*Dot(N.i, N.j*x) + Dot(N.j*x, N.j*x)` and it does not get simplified. I don't want to evaluate it myself.

Comment: and how would you simplify it on paper? Maybe it is the simplest version which you can get without values. Try `simplify(ss)` and you get the same result.

Comment: It is not the simplest version. If you run `simplify(1 + 2*Dot(N.i, N.j*x) + Dot(N.j*x, N.j*x)).doit()` it does simplify it, but not when you run `simplify(ss).doit()`.

Comment: I found that when you skip `factor()` (do `vf = v`) then `simplify(ss).doit()` (and even `simplify(ss)`) gives some simpler version. I don't know why it works in different way. I would rather expect some problem with `.as_independent(Vector)[1]`

Comment: Apparently, SymPy only evaluates `Dot` when both of its arguments are subclasses of `Vector`.

Comment: See discussion here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/18769#issuecomment-634727508

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `as_independent` does not respect the class of Add or Mul that it is dealing with and only uses Mul/Add (instead of VectorMul/VectorAdd in your case). This can be fixed with a transform:

```
>>> from sympy.core.rules import Transform
>>> T = Transform(lambda x: (VectorMul if x.is_Mul else VectorAdd)(*x.args),
...  lambda x: x.is_Add or x.is_Mul and any(isinstance(i,BaseVector)
...  for i in x.args))
>>> vf1.xreplace(T)
N.i + x*N.j
>>> dot(_,_)
x**2 + 1
```